# Excel VBA Condtional VLookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm using a VLookup function to screen `Tabelle5.Range("A:A")` based on identification numbers in `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1)`. If the identifaction number is found in `Tabelle5.Range("A:A")` then various cells from this row should be copied to the right cells in (row) `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1)`.
This is working fine with the following code.

```
Sub VLookup

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim NFR As Long


lastrow = Tabelle5.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NFR = Tabelle3.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row
Set myrange = Tabelle5.UsedRange


For i = 2 To lastrow


On Error Resume Next

    If Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" And Not IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle5.Range("A:A"), False)) Then


        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)


        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 3, False)


        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 4, False)

    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

My challenge here is that there might be cells in `Tabelle3` which do already contain data. This data will be overwritten with the 'new' data from `Tabelle5`. However, it can occur that the 'new' data from `Tabelle5`is an empty cell. This would mean, that I would lose data, because a filled cell would be overwritten by an empty cell.

**EDIT**
Does someone know how to apply Vlookup, only if the identification number from `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1)` is also found in `Tabelle5.Range("A:A")` (that's what I'm using Vlookup for) and in a second step only takes not-empty cells from `myrange Column 2,3, and 4`.

***Example***
The identification number from `Tabelle3.Cells(12, 1)`is found in `Tabelle5.Cells(29,1)`. `Row 29 in Tabelle5`contains following values:

- A29 identfication number
- B29 New Data
- C29 Empty
- D29 New Data

In a next step I want my code only copying the 'New Data' from B29 and D29 to the definied cells in  `Tabelle3` but skipping C29 because it is a empty cell and this might overwrite a already filled cell in `Tabelle3`.

Comment: you have the answer in the body of your question, please re-read your own code first.

Comment: @Banana you mean I can only add another `If-function`? Does this work out? My tries did fail to be honest. If this is not what you mean, I would be happy about a hint in the right direction. :)

Comment: exactly, if you want to check whether or not the cell is empty, then just check whether or not the cell is emtpy... i really dont understand what the problem is

Comment: @Banana I see your point 100% but please take a short look at my edits this might give you a better picture of my problem. I think I need more or less an `if-function within the Vlookup-function`. Looking forward to read your opinion about this. :)

Comment: there can only be 1 item in a cell, either the original value or a formula, you cant put both and activate the vlookup when needed. you can nest the vlookup in an `if` formula but this is just a mess and i wouldnt recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

You could nest your if statement under another if statement, as Banana kindly suggested:

```
If Tabelle5.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" Then

    If Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1) <> "" And Not IsError(Application.Match(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), Tabelle5.Range("A:A"), False)) Then

        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)

        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 3, False)

        Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 4, False)

    End If

End If
```

**UPDATED:**

In this case you can you use if statements to apply each of your VLookups as this:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False) <> "" Then Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)
```

or

```
res1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)
If res1 <> "" Then Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 2) = res1
```

There are surely better ways to this whole logic, but this should help get your code working at least.

Comment: My first idea was similiar to yours but this solutions does only check if `Tabelle5.Cells(7 + i, 1)` is not empty. But I need vlookup to check if the identification numer in `Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1)` is in any row in `Tabelle5.Range("A:A")`. And if vlookup finds this identification number it transfers the values from `myrange Column 2,3 and 4`. But I don't want it to transfer any empty cells.

Comment: Please see my updated answer... the formatting in comments is not quite clear enough...

Comment: I tried this `Then Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Tabelle3.Cells(7 + i, 1), myrange, 2, False)` solution of yours. It does the job, however, the performance is really bad, the code takes ages for exectution. Do you have any suggestion how to improve the performance?

Comment: It takes much longer because you run the same vlookup twice. That's why I've suggested assigning the value of that vlookup to a variable first (which means you are still running the vlookup only once), then use that for if statement/allocation. You could use application.screenupdating = false / application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual (then put back to automatic) to improve the speed... I do advise on trying to learn about arrays and use that instead of accessing the spreadsheet several times.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses `FIND` to get a reference to the correct cell in column A.  It then uses `OFFSET` to check the values in the various columns before copying the values across.
This assumes the identification numbers are unique on both sheets.

```
Public Sub ReplaceFigures()

    Dim rT5_LastCell As Range
    Dim rT3_LastCell As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    'References to last cell in column A.
    Set rT5_LastCell = Tabelle5.Range("A" & Tabelle5.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    Set rT3_LastCell = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Tabelle3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    'rcell will be a direct reference to the column A cell in Tabelle3
    'rFound will be a direct reference to the column A cell in Tabelle5 (or nothing).
    With Tabelle5.Range("A1", rT5_LastCell)
        For Each rCell In Tabelle3.Range("A1", rT3_LastCell)
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=rCell, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext)

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then 'A match has been found.
                'If the Tabelle3 value is empty then copy the Tabelle5 value across.
                If rCell.Offset(, 1) = "" Then rCell.Offset(, 1) = rFound.Offset(, 1) 'column B.
                If rCell.Offset(, 2) = "" Then rCell.Offset(, 2) = rFound.Offset(, 2) 'column C.
                If rCell.Offset(, 3) = "" Then rCell.Offset(, 3) = rFound.Offset(, 3) 'column D.
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

To speed test the macro add the code below and then insert `StartTimer` at the top of the `ReplaceFigures()` code and `StopTimer` at the bottom.

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Public CodeTimer As Long

'^^^^^ Top of module ^^^^^^

Public Function StartTimer()
    CodeTimer = GetTickCount
End Function

Public Function StopTimer()
    Dim FinalTime As Long
    FinalTime = GetTickCount - CodeTimer
    MsgBox Format(Now(), "ddd dd-mmm-yy hh:mm:ss") & vbCr & vbCr & _
            Format((FinalTime / 1000) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss") & vbCr & _
            FinalTime & " ms.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
        "Code Timer"
    CodeTimer = 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you :) But isn't `FIND` a very slow solution when it comes to large data sheets?

Comment: `FIND` should be faster.  It also only looks for the figure once while the original code uses `VLOOKUP` three times and `MATCH` once.  I've added some timing code to my answer so you can compare against your original code.

Comment: The fastest way may be to load the whole dataset into an array and perform the searches in memory rather than on the sheet.  Not sure on the fastest way to search an array though.